# How to separate Javascript quiz answers?

Tags: javascript

I am new(like 4 days ago I was googling how to start an HTML file) to coding and I need help figuring out how to separate my quiz answers into separate lines. Can anyone help me? I tried to find a way to use line breaks but since I am new I have struggled to find a way to do it that doesn't impact the rest of the code. I only included the portion that I need help with. If anyone needs a fuller version, please let me know.

Here is my code:

```js
var myQuestions = [{

    question: "",
    answers: {
      A: 'Emily should tell the other members what role she is now going to fulfill.',

      B: 'Emily cannot do anything until her eight-year term is up.',

      C: 'Emily needs to talk to the other members about a role swap.'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },

];

var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');

var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');

var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);

function generateQuiz(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton) {

  function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer) {

    var output = [];
    var answers;

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

      answers = [];

      for (letter in questions[i].answers) {

        answers.push(
          '<label>' +
          '<input type="radio" name="question' + i + '" value="' + letter + '">' +
          letter + ': ' +
          questions[i].answers[letter] +
          '</label>'
        );
      }

      output.push(
        '<div class="question">' + questions[i].question + '</div>' +
        '<div class="answers">' + answers.join('') + '</div>'
      );
    }

    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
  }

  function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer) {

    var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

    var userAnswer = '';
    var numCorrect = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

      userAnswer = (answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name=question' + i + ']:checked') || {}).value;

      if (userAnswer === questions[i].correctAnswer) {

        numCorrect++;

        answerContainers[i].style.color = 'darkgreen';
      } else {
        answerContainers[i].style.color = 'darkred';
      }
    }

    resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;
  }

  showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);

  submitButton.onclick = function() {
    showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
  }

}
```

Comment: Full Java code for the above:

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript. They're different languages.

Comment: Depending on how you're calling it you may have some issues with calling `showQuestions` since it's nested within the `generateQuiz` function.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use list items for a separate lines of questions like this
check out the documentation and apply css style accordingly.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

```
<ul>
   <li>Ans1<li>

   <li>Ans2<li>

   <li>Ans3<li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put every answer in a `div`; in your code use `'<div><label>'` and
`'</label></div>'`.